# PolymerElements iron-ajax not posting data

Tags: polymer, web-component

This here is my iron-ajax element inside a dom-module:
        
This here is my javascript:

```
var iron_ajax = document.querySelector('iron-ajax');
iron_ajax.body = {"full_names":profile.getName(),"access_token":googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token};
iron_ajax.generateRequest();
```

When I grab the $_POST variable and dump the contents to a file (after encoding them as json) I get []
(That means no data, zero, nothing). When I .log() the variables before sending them to ensure I'm not sending blanks, the values do appear, so it's not that I'm sending blanks.
I think it's a bug, or I just don't understand how it works. Can someone please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution. This is not a Polymer problem. When you POST with content type JSON $_POST will not populate. Try this at server side:

```
    $json = file_get_contents("php://input");
    $_POST = json_decode($json, true);
```

Now your POST-Array will be filled with your request data.

Comment: And don't forget to JSON.stringify your POST data bevor sending the request.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to know what is in your iron-ajax function, but here is what I have and it works.

```html
<iron-ajax auto url="http://localhost:11111/api/Test" headers='{"Accept": "application/json"}' handle-as="json" on-response="ajaxResponse"></iron-ajax>
...

ajaxResponse: function (event) {
  this.response = event.detail.response;
}
```