# iron ajax not posting input data to php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, polymer, polymer-1.0

A portion of the polymer element script:

```
<content>
            <iron-ajax id="plWhois" method="POST" body='{"helper":"plugin", "func":"_pluginsInitAjax", "params":{"domain": "domain", "request_type": "taken"}}' handle-as="json" on-response="handleResponse" debounce-duration="300"></iron-ajax>
            <paper-card heading="Begin the search for your perfect domain name..." image="themes/custom_components/apps/pl-whois/img/who-is.jpg" center>
                <div class="card-content">
                    <paper-input id="plWhoisSearchBtn" type="search" placeholder="e.g. mydomain.com">
                        <iron-icon prefix icon="search"></<iron-icon>
                    </paper-input>
                </div>
                <div class="card-actions s-t">
                    <paper-button on-click="domainAvailability">Search</paper-button>
                    <paper-button>Transfer</paper-button>
                </div>
                <div class="card-actions p-l">
                    <paper-button>buy a domain</paper-button>
                    <paper-button>order hosting</paper-button>
                    <paper-button>make payment</paper-button>
                    <paper-button>support</paper-button>
                </div>
            </paper-card>
  </content>

<script>
        // element registration
        Polymer({
            is: "pl-whois",
            properties: {
                url: {
                    type: String,
                                notify: true,
                    value: ''
                },
                body: {
                    type: Object,
                                notify: true,
                    value: ''
                }
        },
            domainAvailability: function () {
                var domain = this.$.plWhoisSearchBtn.value;

                this.$.plWhois.url = "ajax.php";
                /*this.$.plWhois.body = {"helper":"plugin", "func":"_pluginsInitAjax", "params":{"domain": domain, "request_type": "taken"}};
                */
                this.$.plWhois.generateRequest();
            },
            handleResponse: function(e) {
                console.log(e.detail.response);
            }
        });
    </script>
```

The thing is, the above element is imported, i grab the post data from polymer using:

> $json = file_get_contents("php://input");
>
> $_POST = json_decode($json, true);

which i got [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30661155/polymerelements-iron-ajax-not-posting-data)

the none imported scripts work fine, they post the data, but the imported scripts perform the ajax request but don't post the data to php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still experiencing the same issues, looks like its a bug or something, (a dynamicaly imported script wont send post data during iron-ajax request).

So as a workaround, getting the url, and body value from the element's attributes and then binding them to iron ajax seems to work:

***Iron-ajax:***

> < iron-ajax id="plWhois" method="POST" url="**{{url}}**" body='**{{params}}**' handle-as="json" on-response="handleResponse" debounce-duration="300">< /iron-ajax>

***This script adds the attributes to my element and fires the iron request:***

```
var domain = this.$.plWhoisSearchBtn.value;

this.url = 'ajax.php';
this.params = '{"helper":"plugin", "params":{"0":"whoapi_dot_com", "1":"_test", "2":{"0": "'+domain+'", "1": "taken"}}}';     
this.$.plWhois.generateRequest();
```

***So now this is how my imported element looks like (partial):***

```
//imports
<dom-module id="pl-whois" class="wide-layout-mq">
    <template>
  <style></style>
      <iron-ajax id="plWhois" method="POST" url="{{url}}" body='{{params}}' handle-as="json" on-response="handleResponse" debounce-duration="300"></iron-ajax>

  <content>
            <paper-card heading="Begin the search for your perfect domain name..." image="themes/custom_components/apps/pl-whois/img/who-is.jpg" center>
                <div class="card-content">
                    <paper-input id="plWhoisSearchBtn" type="search" placeholder="e.g. mydomain.com" on-keyup="updateParams">
                        <iron-icon prefix icon="search"></<iron-icon>
                    </paper-input>
                </div>
                <div class="card-actions s-t">
                    <paper-button on-click="domainAvailability">Search</paper-button>
                    <paper-button>Transfer</paper-button>
                </div>
                <div class="card-actions p-l">
                    <paper-button>buy a domain</paper-button>
                    <paper-button>order hosting</paper-button>
                    <paper-button>make payment</paper-button>
                    <paper-button>support</paper-button>
                </div>
            </paper-card>
  </content>
</template>

<script>
    // element registration
    Polymer({
        is: "pl-whois",
        properties: {
            url: {
                type: String,
                notify: true,
      reflectToAttribute: true,
                value: ''
            }
    },
  updateParams: function (e) {
    var domain = this.$.plWhoisSearchBtn.value;

    this.url = 'ajax.php';
            this.params = '{"helper":"plugin", "params":{"0":"whoapi_dot_com", "1":"_test", "2":{"0": "'+domain+'", "1": "taken"}}}';

    if(e.keyCode === 13){
      this.$.plWhois.generateRequest();
    }
        },
        domainAvailability: function () {
    var domain = this.$.plWhoisSearchBtn.value;

    this.url = 'ajax.php';
            this.params = '{"helper":"plugin", "params":{"0":"whoapi_dot_com", "1":"_test", "2":{"0": "'+domain+'", "1": "taken"}}}'; 

            this.$.plWhois.generateRequest();
        },
        handleResponse: function(e) {
            console.log(e.detail.response);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Hope this helps someone who is also stranded!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are missing the `url` attribute for your `<iron-ajax>` call.

Comment: edited my question with the script tag that adds the url

Comment: the website in question is (http://platinumindustriespl.com/cms) , enter a word in the input and hit search, it doesnt send the input data

Comment: here is the full script for the element (https://codeanywhere.com/s/l/zba2QUJSC40pssy3ft3pfeCXCNPNaHoxghVfJ6gTzv71v9KQV25CEIaCCbx62zl3)

Comment: It looks like your Ajax request does finish, as your handleResponse method prints out an object: {err: "The helper class must be of type string, (NULL) given!"}. I would suggest that you debug your ajax endpoint with something like Postman to pinpoint the issue.